# How can I reply to a message after a command in Telebot API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I have this code..

```py
import telebot

#telegram API 
api_key = os.environ['Tele_API_key']
bot = telebot.TeleBot(api_key)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def help_command(message):
    bot.send_message(chat.id,"send a message")

@bot.message_handler(func = lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '/' not in msg.text)
    if message.text == "Hi":
        bot.send_message(chat.id,"Hello!")
```

It sends me "Hello" Everytime I send "Hi"

I want it to be like,
after I do /start
it should ask "send a message"
and when I send "Hello"
it should send "Hi"

But the problem is, it sends "Hi" everytime I send "Hello"

But I only want it to say "Hello" after I send /start and then the "Hi" message

I am beginner, Thanks for the help

Comment: You need to have a state for each chat, which is visible for both message handlers. Define a global dict, save the chat.id if it was provided a /start command, and check the state when it should print "Hello!"

Answer (score 0):

You was created object **msg**  inside *@message_handler* , But haven't used it.

These are silly mistakes

- message.text
- chat.id

Correct ✅

- msg.text
- msg.chat.id

**Final code**

```
@bot.message_handler(func = lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '/' not in msg.text)
if msg.text == "Hi":
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id,"Hello!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=[all_commands['start']])
def say(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "send a message")

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text is not None and '/' not in msg.text)
def sayHi(message):
    if message.text == "Hi":
         bot.reply_to(message, "Hello!")
```

You can reply a message with `reply_to(message, "your reply text")`